# How to write this for loop from C to Python?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I am new to Python, could someone give some pointers as to how this C code can be done in Python:

```
for(i=0, j=0; j<n; i++, j++){
    A[i] = A2[j];
}
```

I gave this as a example. I am working on a web scraping project where I have to compare each word in a string given by the user to another string and should count proximity of each word and the strings I've to compare are in an array.

Comment: What's the point of having both `i` and `j`?

Comment: In Python you [Loop like a Native](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o)

Comment: Check [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to compare corresponding elements in two sequences. Read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

You are basically copying an array, equivalent to a python list. You could simply do:

```
A = list(A2)
```

In a `for` loop scenario (which isn't even needed due to the availability of the `list` call), you'd do:

```
for ind, val in enumerate(A2):
    A[ind] = val
```

you really have many other options too, `A2.copy()`, `A2[:]`, a list comprehension and in most recent python versions `[*A2]`. Python generally makes it very easy to do this.

Comment: Add `A2.copy()` to the list of choices.

Answer (score 1):

Python supports iteration over collections/iterables (so `range`, for example) which are generally discrete. So, you can rewrite that as a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
j = 0
while j < n:
    A[i] = A2[j]
    i += 1
    j += 1
```